# Documentation for mdadm bad block support

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I've read a bit about that mdadm (and the kernel) now have bad block support but I am having a hard time finding any useful documentation on this subject.

1. Is the bad block list for disk X duplicated on all disks in the array?
2. Will a disk with bad blocks be indicated differently in /proc/mdstat ?!
3. If more than two disks in a raid 6 array has bad blocks, is it possible to set a threshold for how many bad blocks is tolerable?!

Comment: I have found [Design notes for a bad-block list in md/raid](http://neil.brown.name/blog/20100519043730).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No
2. Don't know but hope so. You can use --examine-badblocks find out (besides dmesg). 
   See http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.raid/34883
3. No.

Comment: Can you add some additional info from the link.  Link only answers are an issue since links can break.

Comment: Link dead: `No subtopics Nothing found - bye`